# Woocommerce - Cart not updates either adding/deleting items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, content-management-system, cart

When I update the cart adding one item to the cart, or I try removing one element from checkout ... happens:

https://media.giphy.com/media/l0HlGC5W88oXkykZq/giphy.gif

*I update the add to cart button on a item page, well this shows the update number but then updates one less or the same as before*

Where are there the files to check errors?

Thanks